# Eclipse Indigo Market place issue -- permission denied (?)

Tags: windows-7, eclipse-indigo, marketplace

All,

I am trying to get a plugins from the marketplace and I'm getting quite frustrated.  Initially, I was getting exceptions (resolved via another stack overflow post -- thanks), but now I see this:
*emphasized text*

**(X) org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/content.xml**

I do not understand the 'permission denied' in the error log below.
and the error log is showing this:

eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_03
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product

***Warning
Thu May 10 19:15:51 EDT 2012
Connection to http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/p2.index failed on Permission denied: connect. Retry attempt 0 started***

java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.events.socket.SocketEventCreateUtil.createSocket(SocketEventCreateUtil.java:43)
    at 
... snip ....

I have this working correctly/well on the same laptop under VMware/linux, but this Windows 7 version is just not being nice.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is your problem, but I don't see any clear-cut solution:

- http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/d0e8117be5091add

Per the link, please *do* check for firewalls.

Also:

- http://www.java.net/node/703177

  consider adding this to your eclipse.ini:  `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

PS:
Poo-too-weet :)

Comment: The addition of 
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  was all that was necessary!  Thanks!

Comment: The -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true did it for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VPN you need to disconnect the VPN before the update.

also found this here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

If you are behind a firewall (such as a corporate firewall), make sure that you have properly configured your proxy settings in Eclipse. In Eclipse, you can configure proxy information from the main Eclipse menu in Window (on Mac OS X, Eclipse) > Preferences > General > Network Connections.